# Augmented reality feedback

Tags: iphone, camera, accelerometer, augmented-reality

I am developing an application for use in shopping malls. I want to use the augmented reality concept -- when some one is nearer to mall, then I calculate the distance to the mall by getting the current location. Then I display the mall name and distance to the mall on the image in a camera view.

How do I rotate the image if someone is going in the wrong direction? Should I use the accelerometer? I don't know how. Should I correlate the data given by the accelerometer to the mall coordinates? If there is any other possible solution, let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the direction the device is pointing you need to use the compass, not the accelerometer

Take a look at [CoreLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html), specifically the [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) and the [CLHeading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLHeading_Class/Reference/Reference.html) classes.

Comment: sir as u r answer i go for the CLHeading and got a sample code name Teslameter but when i run it on device getting an alert "This device doesn't have the ability to measure magnetic fields"

Comment: Of the iPhones, the compass is available only in the 3GS and 4. I'm not sure about iPod Touches. Devices without a compass have no means to determine which way they are pointing compared to the surface of the earth.

Comment: Extending Tommy's absolutely correct answer, there is a property on `CLLocationManager` called 'headingAvailable' which you can use to find out if your device can give orientation information.